# How to make array of objects that contains key-values in golang?

Tags: go

Let's say, I am iterating some data in go for loop.

```
for _, job := range orderJobs {}
```

for each iteration, I want a new object to be added in array and that object should contain the key value pairs.

So the final output should be something like

```
[
{
"order_id":"123"
"job_name":"JOB1"
}
{
"order_id":"456"
"job_name":"JOB2"
}
]
```

Should I declare and use go maps in this case ? If yes then how exactly I should declare ?

I tried declaring

```
Jobs := make(map[string]interface{})
```

and inserting key value pairs like below inside loop iteration

```
Jobs["order_id"] = "123"
```

it's not serving the purpose of creating array of objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare jobs as a slice:

```
 var jobs []map[string]any
```

Append values to the slice in the for loop:

```
 jobs = append(jobs, map[string]any{"order_id": "123", "job_name":"JOB1"})
```